# Maven War file issue at tomcat server | Ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu, spring-mvc, tomcat, war

I have a problem with my WAR file. I wrote application in Java using maven with Spring boot and Spring MVC. After packaging i pushed file to an ubuntu server at path **/opt/tomcat/webapps**. Currently I have tho WAR files one its test **sample.war** and one **cow.war** its my main application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9grE.png)
However, when I try to access the main page at /cow, Tomcat can't find it if I don't have an index.html file at webapps. Instead, I encounter the following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCx09.png)

*error 404 - Not Found
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.*

if i extract **index.html** file from **/resources/templates/user/** (like in the case of the sample application) i see my login page with is at index.html but without styles
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsRNa.png)

Where could be issue?

I expected that tomcat can find files at ** java nad resources**

I don't have web.xml because i use Spring annotations.